# Convert data from numpy where()

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I have a large set of data and I am trying to get it into a specific form (So i can re-use someone else's code). Here's an example of a smaller set I am working with.

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4],  [0, 3, 6]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [0, 3, 6]])
>>> np.where(a==0)
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 0]))
```

So, what this returns is two arrays in a tuple.
The places that are 0 are (0,0), (1,0), and (2,0)

I'd like to get this data into this form:

```
[(0,0), (1,0),  (2,0)]
```

Which is a list of tuples.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: After `w = np.where(a==0)`, try `print(list(zip(w[0], w[1])))`

Comment: Or for more generality (not necessarily 2 dimensions), use `list(zip(*w))`

Answer (score 1):

Try [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
[tuple(x) for x in numpy.argwhere(a==0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(zip(*np.where(a==0)))
```

How this works:

The `zip` function will produce a sequence of tuples, consisting of:

- tuple containing element 0 from each of its arguments
- tuple containing element 1 from each of its arguments
- ... etc..

So the elements of this sequence will be in the required form if the arguments to `zip` are the elements of the tuple returned by `numpy.where`.  The use of `*` means to expand this tuple to separate positional parameters, as required, rather than passing in the tuple itself.  It is then only necessary to call `list()` to iterate over the iterator returned by `zip` and convert the values into a list.

Example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 6]])  # array in the question

>>> list(zip(*np.where(a==0)))
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)]  # list of 2-tuples

>>> a = a.reshape(1,3,3)  # now a 3d-array (adds slowest varying dimension of size 1)

>>> list(zip(*np.where(a==0)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0)]  # now you get a list of 3-tuples
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
np.argwhere(a==0)
```

output for your example:

```
[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [2 0]]
```

And if you need a list of tuples instead:

```
list(map(tuple,np.argwhere(a==0)))
```

output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
```